# ILMerge with Microsoft.Servicebus.dll for CRM plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-dynamics, ilmerge

I am trying to use ILMerge to merge the `Microsoft.Servicebus.dll` in to my `CRM` plugin dll.  For some reason i keep getting the below error when trying to build my project;

> Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.

The versions I am using for each dll are listed below in the screenshot. I have no idea why this is happening but it works if I change the version of the `servicebus dll` down to 4.1.6.  (If I do that, i get another error when actually running the `CRM` plugin code, so I want to use 4.1.7).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyones info, in the end I didn't merge the servicebus dll in with the plugin code. I called an Azure Function (via a Webhook using WebClient). The Azure function had the servicebus dll and code instead of my plugin. All the plugin ended up doing was calling this function.

```
        public static void FileCopy(string source, string dest, string webhookurl)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient { Headers = { [HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json" } })
        {
            var paramRecord = new Parameters(source, dest);

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (Parameters));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, paramRecord);

            // todo handle the removal of escaped strings better
            var jsonObject = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()).Replace(@"\", "");

            string response = client.UploadString(webhookurl, jsonObject);
        }
    }
```